# Not accessing variable from another file in spite of star import

Tags: python, import, pygame, python-import, public

I have a file "screenDisplay" that is in the same directory as "globalvars." globalvars has a bool called "gameIsMuted." At the top of screenDisplay I have `from globalvars import *`. If I do not use "globalvars.gameIsMuted" in the instance it is used in screenDisplay, then I get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gameIsMuted' referenced before assignment`. If I do use it, then I get `NameError: name 'globalvars' is not defined`. I have checked the spelling. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Give from .globalvars import *, I guess that should do it

Comment: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` What now?

Comment: Give an empty `__init__.py` file in the current folder you have put these files.

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: Your file is not actually named `.globalvars.py` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use global variables either import them like:

```
from globalvars import *
```

Or (probably better):

```
import globalvars
```

The way the variables are referenced then changes:

File: `globalvars.py`

```
gameIsMuted = False
guruMeditationError = False
isukuremuSukiDesu = True
```

Two different examples of usage:

File globals_test1.py:

```
from globalvars import *

print( "Muted ........ " + str( gameIsMuted ) )
print( "Meditation ... " + str( guruMeditationError ) )
print( "Icecream ..... " + str( isukuremuSukiDesu ) )
```

File globals_test2.py:

```
import globalvars

print( "Muted ........ " + str( globalvars.gameIsMuted ) )
print( "Meditation ... " + str( globalvars.guruMeditationError ) )
print( "Icecream ..... " + str( globalvars.isukuremuSukiDesu ) )
```

Note the difference in the usage-syntax.  If the code uses the `from blah import *` syntax, then no qualifier name is needed.  But for the simple `import blah`, the prefix `blah.var_name` is used.

If you don't know which one to use, or don't have a preference, use the latter form.  This makes the code more understandable as it's more clear where the variables are originating from.